# Replace all links(href) in a web page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to replace the URL of all links if found ***sites.com*** on the href ??
For example:

[Original Link](http://one.sites.com/1234/12/page.html) ---> [New Link](http://one.sites.com/)

from this href link

> ```
> http://one.sites.com/1234/12/page.html
> http://two.sites.com/img/dir/index.html
> http://any.sites.com/any/any/any.html
> http://*.sites.com/*/*/*.*
> ```

to be

> ```
> http://one.sites.com/
> http://two.sites.com/
> http://any.sites.com/
> http://*.sites.com/
> ```

i've tried using jquery :

```
$("a[href*='http://one.sites.com/']").attr('href','http://one.sites.com')
```

but it's only going to replace one link.

i think if it with regex, it will be automatically replace all link on any page that have sites.com on each href

```
var isUrl=/(\()((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\))|(\[)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\])|(\{)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\})|(<|&(?:lt|#60|#x3c);)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(>|&(?:gt|#62|#x3e);)|((?:^|[^=\s'"\]])\s*['"]?|[^=\s]\s+)(\b(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+(?:(?!&(?:gt|#0*62|#x0*3e);|&(?:amp|apos|quot|#0*3[49]|#x0*2[27]);[.!&',:?;]?(?:[^a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]|$))&[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]*)*[a-z0-9\-_~$()*+=\/#[\]@%])/img;
```

regex code above successfully check the expression of link like:

```
http://one.sites.com/1/2/page.html
```

how to implement it using jquery? please help

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Do you want to do that on the go? Or are you parsing a static file?

Comment: @putvande i've tried using jquery. i don't know how to use regex on jquery

Comment: Look at my answer below, I think your URL won't contains two times "sites.com/" so you don't need to use regular expressions, use substr() and indexOf() functions instead

Comment: @glautrou $('a[href*="sites.com"]').each(
function(){
   $(this).attr("href", "http://*.sites.com/");
})      the * taken from the link by regex code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('a[href*="sites.com"]').each(function(){
   this.href = this.href.replace(/(.*?sites.com\/)/, function(str, p1){
       return p1
   })
})
```

Or without regExp

```
$('a[href*="sites.com"]').each(function(){
   var index = this.href.indexOf(".com/");
   this.href = this.href.slice(0, index+5)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('a[href*="sites.com"]').each(
function(){
   // Do a substring here to keep the beginning of the path (domain)
   $(this).attr("href", "http://any.sites.com/");
})
```

Comment: regex are difficult to write/maintain, in your case I think you should avoid this, use substr() and indexOf() instead